# create chain of views in navigation item without showing them actually

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

How can i create a chain of viewcontrollers and push them into navigation item without showing them? On the other side is it possible to move backward on the viewcontrollers stack of the navigation item without activating and showing viewcontrollers?

Thanks,

Nava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push a viewController onto a navController using -pushViewController:animated: and setting the animated argument to NO. In this way, you can push a series of view controllers, and only animate the last one. Is this what you're trying to do? You can also pop them off with the animated flag set to NO.

Comment: i have a filesystem tree - folders & files. I want let the user look for a file in a special search tab and when he clicks on the file present it in the filesystem tab in the way, that he will be able naturally navigate back and force from the place the found file is located.